# How to convert a single timeseries in Pandas to multiple series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like following

| timestamp | metric | labels | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | cpu | [region=usa, az=az1] | 1 |
| 12345 | cpu | [region=eu, az=az2] | 2 |
| 12355 | cpu | [region=usa, az=az1] | 3 |
| 12355 | cpu | [region=eu, az=az2] | 4 |

I want to build a timeseries per each label combination. So the result i'm looking for is

| timetsamp | metric | [region=usa, az=az1] | [region=eu, az=az2] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | cpu | 1 | 2 |
| 12355 | cpu | 3 | 4 |

I'm super new to Pandas, and can some one provide me some pointers on how to get there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.pivot`:

```py
print(
    df.pivot(["timestamp", "metric"], "labels", "value")
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
   timestamp metric  [region=eu, az=az2]  [region=usa, az=az1]
0      12345    cpu                    2                     1
1      12355    cpu                    4                     3
```

---

EDIT: If your values in column `labels` are of type `list`:

```py
df["labels"] = df["labels"].astype(str)

print(
    df.pivot(["timestamp", "metric"], "labels", "value")
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Comment: all of your answers looks very promising. But i'm getting an `TypeError: unhashable type : list` .. ill google a bit more on this.

Comment: awsome, pretty cool. It worked. Thanks @Andre

Answer (score 2):

Try via `pivot_table()`:

```
out=(df.astype({'labels':'str'}).pivot_table('value',['timestamp','metric'],'labels')
       .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

output of `out`:

```
  timestamp     metric  [region=eu, az=az2]     [region=usa, az=az1]
0   12345       cpu         2                         1
1   12355       cpu         4                         3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pivot_table`:

```
df['labels'] = df['labels'].astype(str)
print(df.pivot_table("value", ["timestamp", "metric"], "labels").reset_index())
```

Output:

```
labels  timestamp metric  [region=eu, az=az2]  [region=usa, az=az1]
0           12345    cpu                    2                     1
1           12355    cpu                    4                     3
```